# Django Run Server 1.5.1 hangs in all browsers in Windows 8 Machine

Tags: django, python-2.7, windows-8, traceback

Weird Problem : I have a Django site that runs in 2 ways.

1. Through apache/wsgi on :80 normally
2. With python manage.py runserver on :8000 when testing on a pde

Through wsgi everything works fine, but using run server on a pde on windows 8 machine, when I get to any page, the page loads halfway and then just keeps loading forever, without showing trackback.

Some notes about loading 'halfway':

1. It seems to load to exactly the same point for the same error
2. For a different error, it will be a different point (both a different part of trackback and a different file size according to Firebug).
3. For a different browser, it will load to a different point (consistently the same point if the page is reloaded).

Works fine on a different windows/linux machine 7.

Comment: Can you attach some more detailed informations, for example: screenshots?